# How to use a missing primary key when its value is a GUID instead of int? (ASP Net Core, EF, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have boolean functions like this:

```
<h3 class="text-info">@(objRoom.Id != 0 ? "Update" : "Create") Room</h3>
```

How do I change it to make it work when the primary key is a Guid instead of an Int?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - but the context is very much Blazor, that tag was not entirely wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman duh, that's what I get for reading the question instead of the code

Comment: A bit of warning - GUIDs are *terrible* primary keys. Primary keys are usually the clustered index of a table - this defines the order in which the table rows are stored. A random value like a GUID ends up writing rows all over the table, causing fragmentation and forcing the server to jump around index and data pages to find the correct row or rows. At the very least, ensure you use a *sequential* algorithm to generate the GUIDs, preferably in the database itself.

Comment: In SQL Server, [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) generates unique sequential GUIDs. Windows also has a Win32 API method that generates sequential GUIDs

Comment: Thanks for the warning and the tip about Newsequentialid, will def check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Follow as:

1. Change DataType of DB Column With UniqueId from Int/BigInt
2. Create/Change Property Data Type in Model class

   Public Guid Id { get; set;} or if it is nullable then Public Guid? Id { get; set;}

Then check if it is null or not while using Id == Guid.Empty

// Pseudo code

```
if(Id == Guid.Empty ? "Create" : "Update"){
}
```

Mark it Solve if answers your question